# DateUtils is imported from both packages (flutter-app)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a flutter application, and after running the app, i face this error

```
Error: 'DateUtils' is imported from both 'package:calendarro/date_utils.dart' and 
'package:flutter/src/material/date.dart'.
startDate = DateUtils.getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth();
```

This line is in calendarro.dart file provided by flutter itself.
Not only this line, whichever line contains something related to DateUtils, it throws the same error. There are no pre-compilation errors.

Flutter version - 1.22.6
Dart - 2.14
Running on android emulator in android studio(pixel-2 Android9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear. The two packages have a similar class named `DateUtils`. So to resolve it; in the class where you have both imports, assign an alias to one of the packages using the `as` keyword

For example:

```
import 'package:calendarro/date_utils.dart' as dt
dt.DateUtils.getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth(); //call the class using the alias
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I got it now that it was stupid question.