# How to fix dart ambiguous import package error message

Tags: flutter, dart, import, package, visual-studio-debugging

The name `DateUtils` is defined in the libraries `package:calendarro/date_utils.dart` and `package:flutter/src/material/date.dart` (via `package:flutter/material.dart)`.
Try using `as prefix` for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the `imports.dartambiguous_import`

Comment: Can this similar case help you?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328302/dateutils-is-imported-from-both-packages-flutter-app)

Answer (score 4):

you can import packages like this

```
import 'package:calendarro/date_utils.dart' as dateutil;

//and use this as 

dateutil.DateUtils
```